# How can a new SO user make useful comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Saw [this today from a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34417723/1743192):

> (this is a comment since I can not comment until I have 50 rep)
>
> What data are you trying to insert into that table? Is it a string, an
>   int? Also what attributes (columns) does the table have and what data
>   is allowed in those columns?
>
> The query will fail if you try to insert the incorrect data
>   type/restrictions that are defined in your table.

My question is: How can new users who wish to add (useful) comments to questions (be encouraged to) do that?

Comment: They can earn 50 rep and post a normal comment.

Comment: @resueman, totally agree with you. However, in the meantime, before they earn the 50 rep? Are they just supposed to stay "mute" with comments that might turn out useful to providing the answer to a question?

Comment: Considering 50 rep is literally 5 points or 1 mediocre answer, yes, they can just stay mute.